# Gradually dismiss keyboard ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to implement a swipe to dismiss keyboard action on a UITextField, but the only way I know how to dismiss the keyboard is to resignFirstResponder. The behaviour I want is like the native messages app or facebook messenger, where if you drag downwards on the screen the keyboard pans with your finger, and can be gradually raised or lowered.
Anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at the [UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode) (in particular, the interactive mode).

Comment: Top man. tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive